# SQL server query for time zone

Tags: isqlquery

Is there any way to get the current time for particular given time zone?

For EX: GetDateTime("Morocco Standard Time")

It should give the local time of time zone "Morocco Standard Time"

Thanks in Advance,
Merlin

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have an inbuilt function, but you could create a time zone to offset mapping, and retrieve the offset by specifying time zone name.

Comment: Can you gimme an example to get this?

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is quite old, but maybe the answer will help someone.

If you are using SQL Server 2016 you can use new feature [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx). Let's get to the result that you need step by step.

First, use function `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` to retrieve current date and time in UTC time zone. The return type of this function is `DATETIMEOFFSET`, which stores not only date, but also related time zone information:

```sql
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
-- Result is 2016-08-20 13:15:25.3760873 +03:00
```

Then this with `AT TIME ZONE` statement. This returns `DATETIMEOFFSET` in the time zone that you need:

```sql
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Morocco Standard Time'
-- Result is 2016-08-20 11:15:25.3760873 +01:00
```

Additionally if you want to lose time zone information and use `DATETIME`, you can cast the above result to `DATETIME`:

```sql
SELECT CAST( SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Morocco Standard Time' AS DATETIME)
-- Result is 2016-08-20 11:15:25.376
```